# Mean-variance maximization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization, mean-variance, expected-return, markowitz

I denote by $W_0$ and $W_1$ the wealth of an investor at $t=0$ and $t=1$, respectively. Let $r_f$ be the risk free rate, $r$ the vector of returns of the risky assets in excess of the risk free rate, and $w$ the vector of weights of the risky assets. Here is the classical mean-variance optimization problem:
$$\max_{w} E(W_1)-\frac{\gamma}{2}Var(W_1)$$
$$\textrm{st.}\hspace{0.5cm} W_1=W_0(1+r_f+w'r)$$

Injecting the constraint into the optimization problem, the first order condition is thus written as follows:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma} E(r)=W_0Var(r)w$$

My point is that I would like to end up with the classical mean-variance first-order condition:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma} E(r)=Var(r)w$$

But I still have this $W_0$ in the equation... Did I miss something? Could someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I get the maximization problem 
$$ \max\limits_{w} \mathbb{E}\left[W_1\right] - \frac{\gamma}{2} Var(W_1)  $$
$$ st. W_1 = W_0(1 + r_f + w^Tr)$$ 
So we have 
\begin{align*} 
L(w)  &= \mathbb{E}\left[W_1\right] - \frac{\gamma}{2} Var(W_1)\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[W_0(1 + r_f + w^Tr)\right] - \frac{\gamma}{2} Var(W_0(1 + r_f + w^Tr))\\
& = W_0 + W_0r_f + W_0w^T\mathbb{E}\left[r\right] - \frac{\gamma}{2}W_0^2 w^TwVar(r)
\end{align*}
Building the derivative w.r.t. $w$

\begin{align*} 
\partial L(w) / \partial w  &= W_0 \mathbb{E}\left[r\right] - \frac{\gamma}{2}W_0^2 2wVar(r)\\
&= W_0 \mathbb{E}\left[r\right] - \gamma W_0^2 wVar(r) \overset{!}{=} 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\gamma}\mathbb{E}\left[r\right] & = W_0Var(r)w
\end{align*} 
So, I get $ w = \frac{\mathbb{E}[r]}{\gamma W_0Var(r)}$. Set initial wealth $W_0 = 1$ and you get the desired result. The optimal investment strategy $w$ is $W_0$ dependent.

Comment: Thanks, that is basically the calculus I do (except that your matrix calculation is not appropriate: prefer $w'Var(r)w$) and the result I get. So I was wondering whether it was a classical assumption in research papers to set $W_0=1$.

Comment: Do you have a link to the exercise?

Comment: It is not an exercise, it is my work.

Comment: just provide another perspective. the unit between the first and second term is differen. so the penalty gamma should have a unit. so the disapper of Wo can be absorbed by gamma. if you try to maximam sharp ratio you can find what gamma will be